# JSON keys to columns, values to rows SQL bigquery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have rows of JSON values:

```
data_dict = {
    "entity_id": "switch.plug",
    "state": "on",
    "attributes": {"friendly_name": "smart plug"},
    "last_changed": "2023-06-09T03:56:25.283681+00:00",
    "last_updated": "2023-06-09T03:56:25.283681+00:00",
    "context": {
        "id": "ZZ01",
        "parent_id": None,
        "user_id": "1as2298",
    },
}
```

I want the keys for the dict as columns, with `last_updated` as primary key, and the values as the rows for the table. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert the dictionary to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient="index").T

# Set 'last_updated' as the primary key
df.set_index("last_updated", inplace=True)

# Transpose the DataFrame
df = df.transpose()

# Print the transformed table
print(df)
```

Output:

```
last_updated                   2023-06-09T03:56:25.283681+00:00
entity_id                                           switch.plug
state                                                        on
attributes                      {'friendly_name': 'smart plug'}
last_changed                   2023-06-09T03:56:25.283681+00:00
context       {'id': 'ZZ01', 'parent_id': None, 'user_id': '...
```

This is close to something like [this](https://%5B1%5Dhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569168/json-values-to-columns), but I didnt get that quite to work.

How do I do this for SQL for bigquery?

Comment: Then please show us what you have tried

Comment: I think I've solved it simply with the dot notation `SELECT data.entity_id, data.state FROM project.table` was just wondering if there was another way with JSON_EXTRACT functions

Comment: No, that is already an easy way to do it, nothing more needed

Answer (score 1):

Publishing this as community wiki for the benefit of the community. With reference to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569168/json-values-to-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1), you can use the json function [json_extract_array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) combined with unnest to get all the elements of your array as a row then use another [json function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) to extract the value of each element of the array.